# How can call function in dynamic radio button?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5

I have created a quiz app using XML.

My XML code:

```
<item>
 <question type="singleChoice">
 <![CDATA[1.What does CSS stand for?]]>
 </question>
  <answer correct="yes">Cascading Style Sheets</answer>
  <answer>Computer Style Sheets</answer>
  <answer>Colorful Style Sheets</answer>
  <answer>Creative Style Sheets</answer>
</item>
```

and my flex Script code:

```
    protected function buildQuestion():void {
            var question:XML=XML(xmlList[quizIndex])
                answerOption.removeAllElements()
                if(question.question.@type == SINGLE_CHOICE)
                {
                    for each(var tempxml:XML in question.answer)    
                    {
                        var rad:RadioButton= new RadioButton();
                        rad.label=tempxml[0];
                        answerOption.addElement(rad);
                    }       
                }
```

How can I access the current radio button to validate this answer?

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`spark.components.RadioButtonGroup`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html) for that:

```
protected function buildQuestion():void 
{
    var question:XML = XML(xmlList[quizIndex]);
    answerOption.removeAllElements();
    if (question.question.@type == SINGLE_CHOICE)
    {
        var group:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
        group.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onAnswerChanged);
        for each(var tempxml:XML in question.answer)    
        {
            var rad:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
            rad.label = tempxml[0];
            rad.group = group;
            rad.value = tempxml[0];
            answerOption.addElement(rad);
        }       
    }
}

private function onAnswerChanged(event:Event):void
{
    var group:RadioButtonGroup = RadioButtonGroup(event.currentTarget);
    trace ("Selected answer: " + group.selectedValue);
}
```